# Probability, Uniform Distribution.

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose $A$ is a random number chosen uniformly from the interval $(-5,6)$,what is the probability that the quadratic equation $x^2 + Ax + 1 = 0$, has no real root?

This is my approach,

Using the quadratic equation we know,
$b^2 - 4ac < 0$ (has no real roots)

Therefore solving we get $A^2 - 4 < 0$,
hence $-2 < A < 2$

Now we know the $p.d.f$ of a uniform distribution is as [follows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29).

Therefore finally we get,

$P(-2<x<2)= 1/(6+5)$ or $1/11$

Now knowing this is a uniform distribution we can convert the above into a $c.d.f$ 
using integration therefore arriving at the formula on Wikipedia. However since it's uniform distribution why can't we just multiply $1/11$ by $5$ ? Since $[-2,2]$ has $5$ distinct values. Using the formula for $c.d.f$ on Wikipedia I get $4/11$.

Comment: It looks as if part of the time you think of $A$ as a random real. and part of the time as a random *integer* ("Since $[-2,2]$ has $5$ distinct values").

Answer (score 2):

The first part looks fine - $x^2 + Ax + 1 = 0$ having no real solution means $(x + A/2)^2 = A^2/4 - 1$ < 0, which implies $|A| < 2$.

But then you're done! Since $A$ is uniformy distributed on $(-5,6)$, and since $(-2,2)$ lies *fully* within that interval, the probabily is simply the *ratio* of the interval lengths, i.e. $$
  P(A \in [-2,2]) = \frac{2 - (-2)}{6 - (-5)} = \frac{4}{11} \text{.}
$$

You can also derive that using the CDF, of course. The CDF of the uniform distribution on $(-5,6)$ is $$
  F(x) = \begin{cases}
    0 &\text{if $x < -5$} \\
    \frac{x+5}{11} &\text{if $x \in [-5,6]$} \\
    1 &\text{if $x \geq 6$.} \\
  \end{cases}
$$
Therefore, $$\begin{eqnarray}
  P(A \in (-2,2)) &=&  P((X \leq 2) \setminus (X < -2)) = P(X \leq 2) - P(X \leq -2) \\
  &=& \frac{2+5}{11} - \frac{-2+5}{11} = \frac{4}{11} \text{.}
\end{eqnarray}$$